# Serial Reporter

Tags: support

Recently I've been getting notifications telling me that multiple of my questions have been closed in one fell swoop, including a question that's nearly 2 months old already, as can be seen in the screenshots below. None of these questions generally had a negative impact on the community and all were reported for "a lack of context". Is this a serial reporter or is this a general problem with my questions? Thanks!

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know if there's some low-rep user who is targeting you with flags, but while many of the same people are closing your questions, it's not always the same people. I believe you can see who's doing it in the timeline. There are coordinated efforts to close questions in the CURED chat room, or single close votes will put the question in the review queue.

Comment: I will point out that this is a relatively new feature, it went live on November 17: [“Question closed” notifications experiment results and graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356742). So for questions which were closed before that, you did not get any notification. (Which is why closure of your own question was easier to miss before.)

Answer (score 11):

> Is this a serial reporter or is this a general problem with my questions?

I do not know if a serial flagger caused this,
but in my opinion there is a general problem with your (closed) questions:

I checked some of your closed questions and you do not explain enough what you have tried
to solve the problem.
In some examples you only posted the problem without any additional information or context,
and in other cases you wrote wrote only very little about your approach.

Generally, you should describe in more detail, where your approaches failed. Then people who want to help you can usually help you better.